# Is VBA function possible without using the clipboard; make all sheets values only

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function using Excel 2010:

```
Private Function MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly(targetBookName As String)

If Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Name = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Name Then
Else

        Excel.Workbooks(targetBookName).Activate

        Dim mySheet
        For Each mySheet In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                    With mySheet
                                With .Cells
                                            .Copy
                                            .PasteSpecial Excel.xlPasteValues
                                End With
                                .Select
                                .Range("A1").Select
                    End With
                    Excel.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-200
                    Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next mySheet
End If

End Function                        'MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly
```

It works but I'd rather not rely on the clipboard is there an alternative way to make all sheets values only?

Just found an alternative logic I've been using in another program which is relevent to this topic:

```
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rDest As Range

Set rSource = .Range("C5:BG" & .Range("B4").Value + 4)   
Set rDest = mySummaryBook.Sheets("Data_Measures").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    With rSource
          Set rDest = rDest.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    End With
    rDest.Value = rSource.Value
Set rSource = Nothing
Set rDest = Nothing
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
With mySheet.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: <OFF Topic> Is that really your pic? I have been wanting to say that I see a lot of resemblance between your pic and Daniel Craig's pic :) </OFF TOPIC>

Comment: @Siddharth - my wife would agree with you - though I always thought she was joking!

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am sure she is not joking :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout...do you like my profile pic? It's definitely my better side.

Comment: @TimWilliams ok - looks like UsedRange is working well; if I remember right it was a bit unpredictable in earlier versions of Excel - but looks like it is working well now

Comment: @TimWilliams not sure if you used Google Groups for Excel VBA but this answer of yours is similar style to a dude on there called KeepItCool; anyway +1 (but leaving open for a while longer in case anyone else has any other alternatives)

Comment: +1 nice and simple. @whytheq UsedRange can be forgetful of it's actual scope so the normal trick - when the area size is important - is to get it to recalculate. For the value overwrite that Tim used this step is redundant

Comment: @whytheq - I'm not KeepItCool.  I did used to post a lot on usenet (before Google groups!) but I was Tim Williams there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Tim's answer above, which seems to be the most efficient way to do it, you could clean up your code to make it a little faster, less resource intensive. See below. Not huge changes, but will help with processing none-the-less. First don't need Function. Sub will do. No need to select and activate so many things:

```
Private Sub MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly(targetBookName As String)

If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Set wkb = Workbooks(targetBookName)

        With wkb
            Dim mySheet As Worksheet
            For Each mySheet In wkb.Worksheets
                mySheet.UsedRange.Value = mySheet.UsedRange.Value
            Next mySheet
        End With
End If

End Sub 'MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly
```

Comment: You forgot to change the "End Function" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function for this.

Tim has already given you a great method. Here is another way...

```
Sub Sample()
    MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly "Book2"
End Sub

Private Sub MakeAllSheetsValuesOnly(targetBookName As String)
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim formulaCell As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each mySheet In Workbooks(targetBookName).Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set formulaCell = mySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not formulaCell Is Nothing Then
            For Each aCell In formulaCell
                aCell.Value = aCell.Value
            Next
        End If
    Next mySheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: quick question @Siddharth Rout - while I see what you are doing here in that you are only placing values in cells that have formulas, don't you think it would be faster to just do a usedrange.value = usedrange.value, versus looping through all the formula cells one at time, especially on sheets with voluminous formula cells?

Comment: @Scott: Yes you are right. I had already written the code and then I saw Tim's answer. I thought, it would be unfair to use the code he suggested :) His way is definitely faster than mine :)

Comment: makes sense. i can appreciate that :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout analysts at my place need to learn more sql as some of the reports I get to play around with have >20,000 cells of calculations...although on smaller reports I like this idea.